# To re-set focus on Anchor Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used anchor tags on my master page. During TAB key press when focus occurs on particular anchor tag, and then on 
ENTER key press, it redirects to specific linked page. Anchor tag is working fine. But what I want is that
as it opens specific linked page and page is re-loaded then focus should remain on that specific link. So that on next TAB key press
navigation/focus moves to next anchor tag.But what currently  happening is that when we press ENTER key, that anchor tags link open and on TAB
key press default Navigation starts from URL.

```
<div title="Main" >
            <a href="/Home.aspx" id="home">

                <div class="link-title">
                    Home
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div title="Contact" >
            <a href="/Contact.aspx" id="contact>

                <div class="link-title">
                    Contact
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
```

CSS Code is mentioned below:

```
/* To set keyboard focus on Tab press*/
a:focus
{
    outline: 1px dotted black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correctly, here is my offer:
Add a `data` attribute to the `body` element (for example) of each page and set value, for example index of each `anchor` tag, or something as `key`, then on `page_load` with `jquery` read that `data` attribute and set the focus depend on the value.

```
<body data-index='1'>
// rest of the html
```

JS:

```
var index = $('body').data('index');
$anchors.eq(index).focus(); // you need to find `anchor` tags first.
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have not used body tag. Can I use data-index attribute on div element?

Comment: Sure, you can add this to any tag, for more info: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Comment: Please note, the index of `anchor` tags, is `zero-based`, I'll provide jsfiddle link soon.

Comment: I can not run jsfiddle right now, but I provided this link for you, http://chooblebasi.com/factor.html (check the source code for details)

Comment: Also, I think you can use `addClass` instead of `focus`, If you just need different visual effect for `active anchor` tag, for current page. (something like active menu item)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting this solution.

Try this way using `keydown` event for `tab` key alone.

```js
$(function () {
            $("a").keydown(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 9) {
                    var ele = $("a");
                    var len = ele.length;
                    var index = ele.index(this);
                    if (index == (len - 1)) {
                        ele.eq(0).focus();
                        e.preventDefault(); //To prevent event bubbling
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

```css
a:focus {
            color: yellow;
            outline: 1px dotted black;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div title="Main">
        <a href="/Home.aspx" id="home" target="_blank">
            <div class="link-title">
                Home
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div title="Contact">
        <a href="/Contact.aspx" id="contact" target="_blank">
            <div class="link-title">
                Contact
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>   
    <div title="About">
        <a href="/About.aspx" id="about" target="_blank">
            <div class="link-title">
                About
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps you.